# how to display percentage sign in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The data type for the column is decimal(5,2) and i want to show it in my gridview like this:

```
10% or 5% or 18% etc.
```

But it is showing right now in my gridview like this:

400.00% but it should be like this 4%

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Tot_Perc" DataFormatString="{0:P}" HeaderText="Total%" HtmlEncode="true" />
```

what am i doing wrong here?  thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have `DataFormatString="{0:0}%"`

If you want two decimal places, you can use `DataFormatString="{0:0.00}%"`

---

As @adrianbanks mentions, the `DataFormatString="{0:P0}"` format multiplies the number by 100 ... so you may consider storing your percentage as `decimal(5,4)` (store 50% as 0.5, 25% as 0.25, etc) then you can use `DataFormatString="{0:P0}"` as expected.

Comment: `DataFormatString="{0:P0}"` doesn't work as the number is still multiplied by 100.

Comment: You are right ... I edited my answer to highlight the option of changing the underlying column datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `{0:P}` format string, which according to the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) **multiplies the number by 100** and adds the percentage sign. That's why you are getting the wrong number displayed.

To format as you want, use `{0:N0}` and add the percentage sign manually. This formats the decimal as a simple number to zero decimal places.